# Cleanest way to inject into string

Tags: ruby, string, url

We are looking to optimize images with a thumbnail version, which are stored under a funky version of the existing URL:

- Original Image:

  https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg
- Thumbnail Image:

  https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/**thumbnails/medium_**flower.jpg

I was going to look from the end of the string for the last `'/'` and replacing it with `'/thumbnails/medium_'`. In my case this always safe, but I can't figure out this kind of mutation in Ruby on Rails.

```
s = "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg"
img_url = s.split('/')[-1] // should give 'flower.jpg'
```

The issue is to get everything before the last `'/'` to inject in `'thumbnails/medium_'`.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking at the problem the wrong way. What you really want to do is append a subdirectory and modify the file name. One way is to find the last forward slash and work from there, but that is not the only way to approach it, as @sawa demonstrates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg"
img_url = s.insert(s.rindex('/')+1, 'thumbnails/medium_')

# The above approach modifies the original string, if this is unsatisfactory, use:    
img_url = s.dup.insert(s.rindex('/')+1, 'thumbnails/medium_')
```

Comment: Good one, Brad. Can I offer some advice? Using `insert` and `rindex` is imo a good approach. Adding an alternative (regex) method only dilutes your answer. Besides, others have offered solutions using a regex. I  would remove the last line. I would also remove the penultimate line, as it's not the right reason (your solution is simpler and reads better than a regex), but readers will make that determination themselves. You might also consider listing only the second solution and noting that `.dup` could be removed if `s` can be mutated.

Comment: Thanks, @CarySwoveland. I appreciate your advice. I pulled the regex, I agree that it diluted the answer. I couldn't find a great way to modify the other bit clearly, and I'm somewhat reluctant to dramatically modify accepted answers, so I just left that alone. I think it would be fun to benchmark this against http://stackoverflow.com/a/31844415/525478, which looks pretty nice, too. Thanks again, have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg"
img_url = "#{File.dirname(s)}/thumbnails/medium_#{File.basename(s)}"
# => "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/thumbnails/medium_flower.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use `URI` and `Pathname` to work with URLs and file paths:

```
require 'uri'
require 'pathname'

url = "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg"

uri  = URI.new(url)
path = Pathname.new(uri.path)
uri.path = "#{path.dirname}/thumbnails/medium_#{path.basename}"

uri.to_s
#=> "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/thumbnails/medium_flower.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "https://image.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8/flower.jpg"
s.sub /([^\/]+)$/, 'thumbnails/medium_\1'
```

The `s.sub`'s 2nd argument should be quoted with **single quotation mark**, or you have to escape the backslash in the `\1` part.

### UPDATE

```
s.sub /([^\/]+?)(?=$|\?|#)$/, 'thumbnails/medium_\1'
```

In case there's a query string or a fragment or both, behind the path, which contains slashes.

Answer (score 0):

It's `#[Range]` method what you need:

```
# a little performance optimization - no need to split split string twice
parts = s.split('/')
img_url = parts[0..-2].join('/') + "/thumbnails/medium_" + parts[-1]
```

On a side note. If you are using some Rails plugin for handling images (`CarrierWave` or `Paperclip`), you should use built-in mechanisms for URL interpolation.